# Why are there two interface declarations in default Xcode templates?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Very recently all the new classes I create in Xcode are prefaced by this extra interface in the .m file:

```
@interface NewViewController ()

@end
```

What does Apple expect me to put here and how is it different from the `@interface` declaration in my .h file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a [class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html). In a nutshell, you declare your class's public interface in the header and use a class extension to declare any private interface you might want to provide (e.g. properties for which you want accessors but which you don't want to make public).